# Parameter-Read-Timeout in Wildfly 9.0.1.Final

Tags: java, java-8, wildfly

We have stumbled accross some odd (currently non-reproducable) behaviour in the JDK8_74/Wildfly 9.0.1.Final. Upon parsing the parameters of a post-request the worker thread starts an infinite-loop into the native method `PollArrayWrapper.poll0(long, int, long)`. The thread consumes 100% CPU load on one core.

```
mServlet.java:468 io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameterValues(String)
  HttpServletRequestImpl.java:679 io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData()
 ...
    SelectorImpl.java:86 sun.nio.ch.PollSelectorImpl.doSelect(long)
      PollSelectorImpl.java:87 sun.nio.ch.PollArrayWrapper.poll(int, int, long)
        PollArrayWrapper.java:115 sun.nio.ch.PollArrayWrapper.poll0(long, int, long)
```

Has anyone seen this? It seems to pop up in different projects on different occasions since 2005 and has been reported several times as JDK Bug and those have been marked fixed.

Has anyone any idea, how to force Wildfly to use a timeout on the `poll0` Method?

Kind regards, 
Jonathan

Comment: Is this when using https listener?

Comment: @ctomc We are using http, not https.

Comment: what is your exact OS?

Comment: @ctomc OS is SLES 11.4.23

Comment: that means linux kernel 2.6.37 right? if not please update post with output of uname -a command. 2.6 kernel had few known issues around this. Is there any chance you could try running your code on any newer kernel? 3.x preffered, SLES 12 maybe or any other distro that uses newer kernel.
JDK you are using is oracle's or openjdk?

Comment: @ctomc Our SLES SP4 comes with kernel 3.0.101-68-default, we are running on arch amd64 and using the Oracle-JDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ctomc implied, this issue is very likely a non-resolved jdk-bug. Our software is running on quite a vew different execution environments and we have ever seen this issue on the SLES 11.4.23 system.

A possible solution is to employ thread-encapsulation in a hystrix style: encapsulating the critical call within a `Callable` and therefore allowing to implement some form of watchdog/time-out.